# Удаление элементов из VueJS

Tags: vue.js, eventbus

Вообщем у меня есть такая функция:

```
deleteSection(id) {
    this.$store.dispatch('deleteSection', id).then((response) => {
        EventBus.$emit('removeSectionEl', id);
    }).catch((error) => {});
}
```

Я вызываё её в одном месте и потом в компоненте родителе родителя срабатывает вот такой слушатель:

```
EventBus.$on('removeSectionEl', function (id) {
    let section = this.sections.findIndex(sec => sec.id === id);
    this.sections.splice(section, 1);
});
```

Но при этом почему хватаю такую ошибку:
`Error in event handler for "removeSectionEl": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined"`

Что я делаю не так ?? Мне просто нужно обновить список после удаления эелемента.

Comment: Написано же что findindex в this.sections undefined. Смотрите в this.sections

Comment: @RavenTheX я понимаю что findIndex не пожет быть прочитан, но это функция для поиска в массиве, так что мне она по сути нечего не говорит.
И в другом месте она буквально с этими же данными работает, и я бы не парился если бы список автоматически обновился после удаления

Comment: Выведите в той функции в консоль this.sections. Что пишет?

Comment: Просто скорее всего проблема в том, что я sections получаю из секции computed, может можно как-то заставить повторно вызвать эту функцию, чтобы обновить список

Comment: @RavenTheX а вообще выдаёт undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка у Вас в том, что используется обычная функция:

```
EventBus.$on('removeSectionEl', function (id) {
    let section = this.sections.findIndex(sec => sec.id === id);
    this.sections.splice(section, 1);
});
```

В результате контекст `this.sections` теряется и смотрит не на компонент! а на слушатель. Используйте стрелочную функцию

```
EventBus.$on('removeSectionEl', (id) => {
    let section = this.sections.findIndex(sec => sec.id === id);
    this.sections.splice(section, 1);
});
```

Comment: О и правда робит.